# SAP GUI Scripting Recording Only Part of Action is Captured

Tags: vba, session, scripting, sap-gui

I am using the Recorder of SAP GUI Scripting to Record the following steps:

1. Enter transaction "/oTableA"
2. Press Enter go to "TableA"

---

3. Press "Get Variant"
4. Choose "Layout0"
5. Press "Execute"
6. Export to Excel etc.

**But no matter, how many times I try. The recording script only capture from step 1) to step 2), nothing was recorded from step 3) to the end.**

Here is the script part from step 1) to step 2)

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/oTableA"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

And I tried to record the from TableA screen(after step2) from step3 to step5, the script part:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
....Same as previous
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[2]").press
```

I try to concatenate two parts of script to following:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
...same as previous 
End If
# step 1-2
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/oTableA"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
# step 3-5
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press  **-This is Line 18**
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[2]").press
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QyaQ.png)
This script throw an error on line 18. Can I know why, because the same script oks separately for execute step 3 - step 5, but not working when I concatenate it with step 1 to step 2. Or what kind of change should I make?

Thanks very much!

Comment: /o opens a new sessions which means script recorder does not have a connection to this session and cannot record anything. Try /n instead.

Comment: i.e. the recorder can record only one session at a time - it's not possible to start another recorder for another session while the recorder is running (I tried to start a new SAP Logon but only one can run at a time, I tried to log in the same system or in another system -> no way)

Comment: @SandraRossi  thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Storax 's solution helps me solved my problem! thankyou so much!!

Comment: Great. Maybe you can add an answer so that future visitors will know what to do more precisely?